Redirect a Subdomain from a domainhoster to a webspace with path at other provider
I have one provider who takes care of my Domains (Provider A) and another one where my dedicated server is hosted (Provider B).
I want to use a sub-domain me.comp.com at Provider (A) that shall route to a webspace in a path below the htdocs folder like /htdocs/app2 at Provider (B).
In the end I want to see in the URL area of the browser me.comp.com/index.php whereas Index.php is the start of the app.
I was able to route from Provider A to Provider B with an A-record in the DNS of the domain like
me  60  IN A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
I also checked if in the XAMMP Installation the apache httpd.conf has this entry
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf  which was enabled
So I adapted the vhosts like this
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/app2"
   ServerName me.comp.com
   ServerAlias me.comp.com
   ErrorLog "logs/me.comp.com-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/me.comp.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost> 

This works so far; I can enter the subdomain me.comp.com and reach the host at Provider B.  But I have instead of me.comp.com/index.php I see xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app2 in the URL window of the browser.But the application runs and is available.
So I tried to setup a .htaccess with
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule (.*) http://me.comp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

I succeeded now partly as the URL changes. I receive now me.comp.com/app2 instead of me.comp.com/index.php. but no IP anymore. However, with this version I cannot access the content anymore, I just receive a blank page instead of the index.php in the folder /app2 and still the path is shown which I do not want.
What I would like to have
Subdomain       Server
me.comp.com ->  me.comp.com/index.php (within the subfolder /app2 of /htdocs)
Anyone has a hint? Seems I made a mess :)
